# Using Opencv to perform PCA analysis in C++

Tags: c++, opencv, pca

I haven't found a working example of implementing PCA analysis using Opencv that suits my case, so I'm not sure what is wrong with my implementation, which follows:

```
void PreProcessor::performPca()
{
    const int type = CV_64F;
    cv::Mat pt_mat = cv::Mat::zeros(numPatients, numFeatures, type);
    for (int y = 0; y < numPatients; y++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < numFeatures; x++)
        {
            pt_mat.at<double>(y,x) = features[y].at(x);
        }
    }
    cv::PCA pt_pca(pt_mat, cv::Mat(), CV_PCA_DATA_AS_ROW, numFeatures);
    cv::Mat dataprojected(pt_mat.rows, numFeatures, pt_mat.type());
    for (int i = 0; i < pt_mat.rows; i++)
    {
      dataprojected.row(i) = pt_pca.project(pt_mat.row(i));

    }
    features.clear();
    for (int i =0; i< dataprojected.rows; i++)
    {
        std::vector<double> pcaFeat = dataprojected.row(i);
        features.insert(std::pair<int, std::vector<double> >(i, pcaFeat));
    }
}
```

This member function attempts to find the principal components of `features`, which is already filled and is declared as `std::map<int,std::vector<double>> features` . At the end it refills it with the principal components. `NumPatients` is the number of vectors in `features` and `numFeatures` is the number of elements in a vector. 
The above code debugs and runs, but the resulting `features` is mostly filled with zeros.
Is there something wrong with my understanding of how PCA of Opencv works?

Comment: May be your data are linearly dependent.
Did you check it on synthetic data, or on random set ? 
Also it would be good idea to compare it with MATLAB results.